# Prolog - subtract values of predicate

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog and I have these facts:

```
% Fatos
gerou(darthVader,princesaLeia).
gerou(darthVader,lukeSkywalker).
gerou(padmeAmidala,princesaLeia).
gerou(padmeAmidala,lukeSkywalker).
gerou(padmeAmidala,kyloKen).
gerou(hanSolo,kyloKen).

idade(darthVader,45).
idade(princesaLeia,34).
```

where `idade` means the age of `darthVader` and `princesaLeia`. I am trying to do a rule that calculates the difference age between both. I have tried this but it doesn't works:

```
% Regras
diferenca_idade(idade(X, A), idade(Y, B), Z) :- Z is (A - B).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This should give the correct result, and some wrong ones. Maybe you need to make sure `X` and `Y` are not the same.

Comment: `diferenca_idade(X, Y, Z) :- idade(X, A), idade(Y, B), Z is A-B.`

Comment: @TomasBy it worked! Thanks a lot.